# How to replace ServiceLocator in Startup class

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth, unity-container, owin

I'm using Owin (OAuth), ASP.NET WebApi2 and Unity together with custom Authorization server provider (SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider) based on OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider, but with my implementation of Unit of work and Repository pattern.
My problem is resolving dependencies in Startup class, I mean Startup class needs SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider and SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider needs IUserOrchestration and IUnitOfWorkFactory. Dependencies in SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider are fine, problem is in Startup class, because Startup class has to have constructor without parameters and property injection not working - dependencies are inject too late.
Only working solution is based on ServiceLocator and honestly, it's bad idea.
I need find another working solution...

```
public class Startup
{
    private SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider _simpleProvider;

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        // Create instance for Unity container - let's try to run!
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);

        // Include project classes to IoC container
        new CommonUnityConfiguration().Configurate(container);
        new RepositoryUnityConfiguration().Configurate(container);
        new OrchestrationUnityConfiguration().Configurate(container);
        new ServerUnityConfiguration().Configurate(container);

        // HERE COMES PROBLEMATIC LINE
        _simpleProvider = container.Resolve<SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider>(); // Ugh! ServiceLocator - not pretty, but how can I replace it? :(

        ConfigureOAuth(app);
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll); // enable CORS
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = _simpleProvider
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }
}
```

and implementation of SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider:

```
public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private readonly IUserOrchestration _userOrchestration;
    private readonly IUnitOfWorkFactory _unitOfWorkFactory;

    public SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(IUserOrchestration userOrchestration, IUnitOfWorkFactory unitOfWorkFactory)
    {
        _userOrchestration = userOrchestration;
        _unitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory;
    }

    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        using (IUnitOfWork uow = _unitOfWorkFactory.Create())
        {
            var user = _userOrchestration.FindUser(context.UserName);
            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

        context.Validated(identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution, i have the same problem. Thnx :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a Service Locator there, rather, this looks like a Composition Root.

Although it is disputable whether or not the Composition Root is a place to resolve dependencies and use them or only configure them, I wonder where actually you use the resolved instance - in the code snippet the instance is resolved and never used (!?).

You could possibly refactor this to split it into two classes of different responsibilities - have a clean Composition Root where you only configure and other initialization classes where you actually use the configuration. Or rather, decide which of the two you want your startup class should be.

Comment: Yeah, you right, Configuration method take care of Composition root, but line `_simpleProvider = container.Resolve<SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider>();` actually is Service locator -> you want SOMETHING (SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider in this case) from SOMEWHERE throught SOMEONE. Basically it is Service locator pattern. But I think you catch my point. And I use them, look at method ConfigureOAuth; in creating new instance of OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions class. Yeah, I can, and actually I did it, but it not solve my problem. I wonder if and how I can replace service locator... TY4reply

Comment: "Although it is disputable whether or not the Composition Root is a place to resolve dependencies and use them or only configure them" here you catch point of question. No, you shouldn't. Composion root was at beginning in static method WebApiConfig.Register(). But because I added Owin(Katana) to project, entry point starts to be Startup class method Configuration and I need to setup Authorization at startup - authorization trought db server and I'm using UoW I need to create one throught factory. But because Unity wasn't start and ready in this phase of life cycle Startup class I have to move

Comment: Since it is a composition root, you don't have to create the instance with the container. Rather, you can just create it with `new`. That's why CR is for, to configure dependencies using concrete types. The issue stems from the fact that you violate SRP here, your class has two different responsibilities. Another option then would be to refactor and split responsibilities. Take out the CR and in the startup class, use a local factory to get the instance configured in the CR.

Comment: No, I can't. My IUnitOfWorkFactory is in different project and IUserOrchestration too - only way, how can I get instance is throught Unity. SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider depend on this classes.

Comment: Yes, you can. A local factory is declared near the class it creates but internally uses a provider that is configured in the composition root. And you inject a provider that uses unity. Local factories are considered an alternative to service locators.

Comment: If I'm understand well, you mean something like this `var foo = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(container.Resolve<IUserOrchestration>(), container.Resolve<IUnitOfWorkFactory>()); container.RegisterInstance(typeof (SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider), foo);` Trought factory is actually same principe. So I'm not sure if it help me...

Comment: I mean `new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider( new ConcreteUserOrchestration(), new ConcreteUnitOfWorkFactory() )`. Since you are in the composition root, you have all the knowledge of concrete type mappings.